# Fluorescent compensation with Lee Seven5?

Tags: color-filters

I am planning to get the Lee Seven5 for ND and polarizing filters for an MFT system. However, I would also like to do certain types of color balancing, especially fluorescent balancing, since I shoot often in museums or other indoor settings with fluorescent lights.

Lee has a fluorescent correction gel set. Is this set compatible with the Seven5?

Comment: A ColourChecker Passport would obviate the need for guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Lee's technical optical filters, then no, their technical filters are 100mm x 100mm, so only fit their 100mm system. From the [fluorescent correction filters page](http://www.leefilters.com/index.php/camera-directory/camera-dir-list/category/fluorescent-correction),

> Available in resin or polyester for the 100mm System.

If you're talking about their fluorescent correction gels, then, no. Gels are for correcting lighting *at the source*. Generally, gels are not optically clear enough to be used in front of the lens.

Comment: Ok, what are my options for fluorescent color correction, then? The 100mm setup will be gigantic for my 4/3rds. Do they sell 75mm holders that I could just manually cut the resins for myself?

Comment: True gels (not cellophane 'gels') were once commonly used in stamp sized holders at the *rear* of lenses. They were optically superior to many flat glass filters. A few current Canon and Nikon lenses still have a holder for them back there. [Why would I use a rear gelatin filter over a front filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/why-would-i-use-a-rear-gelatin-filter-over-a-front-filter) There are also [lenses with drop-in filter holders that can use gel filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/why-would-i-use-a-rear-gelatin-filter-over-a-front-filter).

Answer (score 0):

As @scottbb mentioned The Lee gels are meant to filter the light source. Usually for mixing fluorescent lights with other sources. You *can* put them on the camera, but it will be optically worse and won't do anything you can't accomplish in post.

Since you are shooting digitally – you mentioned MFT – you are better off doing overall color balancing in the computer.

Also worth noting: modern fluorescents can be many different colors, not just the green the Lee filters are compensating for.

Using a color standard like @Tetsujin suggested is a good idea, but don't try to match it so closely that the image looks flat. Every client I've worked with preferred a good looking photograph to an accurate one even for reproduction work.